# I assume this means next episode number 6 "第 六話"

Tags: words, kanji

I've noticed this season two shows end the preview with the episode number and title underneath - 第六話 - but this confuses me.

How should I read this?  Is 話 still はなし or is it something else?  What is the first kanji?  I know 六 (ろく) for sure but I need help understanding how to read this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reading for 話 as a counter, [according to jisho.org](http://jisho.org/word/%E8%A9%B1-1), is わ.

The first kanji is read だい, and is a prefix for ordinal numbers. So the whole thing is read だいろくわ and means "sixth episode".